# Vertical align text with floating inside Containing Div

Tags: css, html

There's a piece of html:-

```
<div class="field-display">
    the text here
    <a class="delete">x</a>
</div>
```

The anchor element is button which has `float: right;` CSS property. The CSS for the div is:-

```
.field-display {
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px 15px 2px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But `vertical-align: middle;` is not working. Any Idea how to align text in middle of the div?

Comment: for **IE8+** , give `field-display` `display:table-cell` because `vertical-align: middle;` is not supposed to work on `block` level elements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display: table-cell;` to your div.

```
.field-display {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 15px 2px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/96d7x/)**

**Side Note :**  `display: table-cell;` is supported by IE8 and above..!

Comment: looks like specifying the width is also important.